# awk sub is doing global substitution instead of only first occurence

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have this csv file separated by semicolon. I want to replace only the first occurrence of 1 with 77 in the 8th field.
But the awk command is replacing all 1s with 77 in the 8th field.
what do i do?

original csv

```
1;abc;1;;;;;1;;1;;1;;;;;1;;;1;;
2;def;1;;;;;1;1;1;;;;;1;;;;1;;;
3;ghi;1;;;;1;1;1;1;;1;;1;1;;;;;1;;
4;jkl;1;;;;;1;;1;;1;1;;;1;;;;1;;
```

I tried this

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {sub(1, 77, $8)} {print}' ser.csv > tmp.csv
```

i was expecting this

```
1;abc;1;;;;;77;;1;;1;;;;;1;;;1;;
2;def;1;;;;;1;1;1;;;;;1;;;;1;;;
3;ghi;1;;;;1;1;1;1;;1;;1;1;;;;;1;;
4;jkl;1;;;;;1;;1;;1;1;;;1;;;;1;;
```

but i am getting this.

```
1;abc;1;;;;;77;;1;;1;;;;;1;;;1;;
2;def;1;;;;;77;1;1;;;;;1;;;;1;;;
3;ghi;1;;;;1;77;1;1;;1;;1;1;;;;;1;;
4;jkl;1;;;;;77;;1;;1;1;;;1;;;;1;;
```

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: .... and then format your input, output, and code as Code Blocks.

Comment: Also [edit] your question to clarify what you mean by `first occurrence` - tell us if you mean a) `first occurrence in each line` or b) `first occurrence in each file` or c) `first occurrence across the whole input` or d) something else.

Comment: "Global substitution" means that all possible substitutions are made in the current string (which is the current line if not specified), or the current field (as in your $8), or the specified variable. The gsub() itself (as with all actions) is executed for every input line (unless there are further patterns or tests which avoid gsub() being executed).

Comment: Easier to use sed 's/;1/;77/' your_input

Comment: @dhm that wouldn't work in a couple of different ways.

Comment: @Paul_Pedant but i used sub and not gsub . so i thought it should only work at the first occurrence.

Comment: @EdMorton first occurence in the 8th field. (8th column) . There are many 1s in that column and I want only the first 1 to change to 77. my code was converting all 1s to 77. I didn't even use gsub i was using sub which i believed only replaces the first occurence.

Comment: Note that there is a subtle difference between "the first `1` in the 8th field" (would change `100` in the first record's 8th field into `7700`), "the first 8th field that is `1` (would only change `1` but not e.g. `11` or `100`, and may not change the first record at all), and "the 8th field of the record _whose 1st field is `1`_" (the record of interest may not be the first one if the data isn't sorted).

Comment: @EmmanuelFernando  The `sub()` is also executed for *every* input line, even though it only replaces the first occurrence in the current string (in your case, $8 of the current input line). If you want to have the whole field checked for the value `1`, the first arg to sub should be a pattern like `/^1$/` which anchors the start and end of the field.

Comment: @EmmanuelFernando I think the problem you're having is in always saying/thinking "the first occurrence" but never completing that statement by adding "in <something>". sub() does replace just the first occurrence **in a string**, not **in a file**, nor **in all the input**. You apparently want to replace `the first occurrence in the input` but have written code to replace `the first occurrence in each $8`. You said `first occurence in the 8th field` but thats still vague as it doesn't say `first occurence in the first 8th field in the input` or `first occurence in every 8th field in the input`

Comment: and from [your comment under my answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729768/awk-sub-is-doing-global-substitution-instead-of-only-first-occurence/729770?noredirect=1#comment1383974_729770) you don't even really want to replace `the first occurence of 1 in the first 8th field in the input`, you want to replace `the contents of the 8th field the first time it's exactly 1 across all the input`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that by "first occurrence" you mean "first occurrence across the whole input", then this is probably what you want using any awk (untested):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} !f && sub(1, 77, $8){f=1} {print}'
```

The above replaces the first `1` that occurs in the 8the field across all your input. If instead you want to replace the 8th field the first time it has the value 1 across all your input then that'd be this (or similar):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} !f && ($8==1){$8=77; f=1} {print}'
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This works exactly as i want. Please help me understand what is !f and {f=1}

Comment: Ok, So it does work but i noticed a new issue. If the number is 12 instead of just 1 the command is replacing the 1 of 12 also with 77. How to make awk search for strictly only 1  and do the replacement. if the column contains lets say . 12, 1 , 1, Then i want only the middle 1 to be replaced and not the 1 of 12. The middle 1 is the first occurrence of 1 as a whole word .

Comment: @EmmanuelFernando  Use `sub(/^1$/, 77, $8)`. `sub()` first field is a pattern (regular expression). The `^` and `$` anchor the pattern to the start and end (respectively) of the string.

Comment: @EmmanuelFernando  `! f` means `not f` -- it is checking that `f` has not already been set non-zero. `{ f = 1 }` sets `f` when a `sub` has succeeded. Together, this makes a mechanism where matches after the first are disabled. The name `f` is probably chosen to represent "first".

Comment: @EmmanuelFernando  The requirement to change part of a field (e.g. `$8` is `12, 1, 1` and becomes `12, 77, 1`) is a completely different kind of problem. Please edit your question to show the actual requirement and some representative data examples -- adding this kind of detail in a comment is unhelpful.

Comment: @EmmanuelFernando  Also important to state whether the internal spacing of $8 has to be respected, and whether the subfield separator is always `,`. Finding the first `1` that is not part of a longer number, and may be in any position within some arbitrary text (including alone, at start, or at end) is not easy. In the example `12, 1, 1` you give in the above comment, the word you refer to is `1,`. If you want to split $8 as numbers separated by anything else and search for the first `1`, you need to split the field, preserving the separators, and rebuild the field again after.

Comment: @EmmanuelFernando change `!f && sub(1, 77, $8){f=1}` to `!f && sub(/^1$/, 77, $8){f=1}` or `!f && ($8==1){$8=77; f=1}` or similar.

Comment: awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} !f && ($8==1){$8=77; f=1} {print}'    this one works perfectly. I realized now the difference between input and string. i had unclear ideas about that before. Thanks a lot for guiding me.